# Show that all solutions of the differential equation $x'+a(t)x=b(t)$ converge to zero when $t \to \infty$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a, b: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions such that $a(t) \leq c >0$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $$\lim_{t \to \infty} b(t)=0$$
Show that all solutions of the differential equation $x'+a(t)x=b(t)$ converge to zero when $t \to \infty$.

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe this can be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grönwall%27s_inequality

Comment: Try to solve $x'+a(t)x=0$ first.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=0$ and $a(t) = \min(1,e^{-t})$.

Consider the solution to the equation $\dot{x}= -a(t) x$ such that $x(0) = 1$.

It is not hard to check that $x(t) = e^{e^{-t} -1}$ for $t \ge 0$, but $x(t) \to {1 \over e} >0 $.